# Understanding Firebase cloud function "cold start"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

It is mentionned in the doc that

> Functions are stateless, and the execution environment is **often**
> initialized from scratch, which is called a cold start.

This statement implies that  * *sometimes* *, functions are **not** initialized from scracth and the state can be reused.

Is this a reliable assumption ?

## Illustration

```
var count = 0; // global variable

functiion mycouldFunction(){
  count ++;
  return count;

}
```

If I call `myCloudFunction` twice with X amount of time apart, should I expect it to return '1' then '2'

Then a 3rd call after Y amount time, I should expect it to return '1' again ?

If that is true, what is the value of X and Y ?

Comment: my bad https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations

Comment: You've reached the correct section of the documentation. I think you'd find the following [video](https://youtu.be/v3eG9xpzNXM) very useful as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions will indeed **sometimes** reuse server instances to handle multiple requests, as an optimization.  There is no guarantee if or when this can happen.  Unless you are implementing some sort of optimization on your own (memory caching, for example), it's not advisable to store anything in global memory, since your function could be subject to a cold start for any one of its invocations.

Answer (score -1):

No, cloud functions are stateless so every time you call `myCloudFunction` it would return 1.

To achieve what you want you would need to store the updated value in Firestore or RTDB or similar and read the updated value on each load.

What "Cold Start" refers to has nothing to do with the above, it's in reference to how functions are served.  GCF will "turn off" functions that are infrequently used so they may respond slower than functions that are "turned on" and ready to receive requests.

Comment: This isn't really true.  While functions are stateless in a general sense, Cloud Functions will actually reuse server instances, along with any global memory, for some future invocations.  It's just not guaranteed to do so.